# Constructing an LL(1) grammar with substituion, factoring and left recursion removal

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, left-recursion, pushdown-automaton

Using any of the techniques (substitution, factoring, left-recursion removal),
construct an LL(1) grammar accepting the same language as G.

```
G over Σ = {0, 1, 2}:
    S → Y | 1X
    X → 1X | 0
    Y → Y0 | 1X1 | 2X2
```

I did this so far:

X is left recursive so:

```
X -> 1F | 0F
F -> 1F | e
```

What else would i need to do to construct an LL(1), could i factor Y?

Answer (score 0):

First, X is not left recursive, as its RHS doesn't begin with X. Rather it's tail-recursive and it's all right. However Y -> Y0 tells you that Y is left-recursive. In this case you do the following:

```
S -> Y | 1X
X -> 1X | 0
Y -> 1X1F | 2X2F
F -> 0F | e
```

You may also want to add and epsilon rule to X as well making it

```
X -> 1X | 0 | e
```

just to make sure you'll never end up with infinite sentences.